# How to change the colour of parts of a 3D plot, rather than the whole figure?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, boolean-computation

By exporting Matlab data to a `txt` file and importing it with `List3DPlot`, I plotted the density of states in a nanowire sandwiched between two bulk materials:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
ListPlot3D[
    Transpose[ReadList["DOS_E=-2.5_2.5_rL=0_rR=0.1_eta=0.01_L=10.txt",Number,RecordLists->True]],
    PlotRange->All,
    Ticks->{{{50.5,"0"},{30.5,"-1"},{70.5,"1"}},{{25.5,"0"},{125.5,"L"}},Automatic},
    AxesLabel->{"\[Epsilon]/\[CapitalDelta]", "x", "DOS"},
    ImageSize->750,ViewPoint->{150,-250,250}
]
```

[image: Density of states as a function of quasiparticle energy and position in the wire]

For completeness, the text file with the data points is available on [Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6645244/DOS_E%3D-2.5_2.5_rL%3D0_rR%3D0.1_eta%3D0.01_L%3D10.txt) (which should be saved as `DOS_E=-2.5_2.5_rL=0_rR=0.1_eta=0.01_L=10.txt` in the notebook folder).

The part between `0<x<L` is the nanowire, the parts `x<0` and `x>L` are the bulk materials (normal metal on the left, superconductor on the right). In order to clearly show the structure of the sample, the part of the plot that represents the nanowire should have a different colour.

**Question:** How can the part `0<x<L` be coloured with a different colour function than the parts `x<0` and `x>L`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think what you need is `ColorFunction` and `ColorFunctionScaling`.

In `ColorFunction` you can set the color in different regions according to the points' {x,y,z} coordination. And I think what you need is just setting some part in a color (in my code, Bed) and the other in another color(in my code, Blue). Then, simply create a function discribing this and set `ColorFunctionScaling` to False:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, If[5 >= x >= 0, Blue, Red]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: sample img]

A more beautiful image, illustrating that you can add whatever you want in `ColorFunction` and the usage of `ColorData` to easily and elegantly represent your data:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   If[5 >= x >= -5, ColorData["BrightBands"][(x + 5)/10], 
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z]]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: img2]

Comment: FYI if you export and upload graphics as PNG rather than JPG you will get much better quality.

Comment: Especially the `ColorData` part is useful, as so much information is lost with the single colours.

Answer (score 3):

A recommendation to the question poser:  Pose your question in the absolute simplest terms, limiting to the minimal example that addresses your point.  There is no need here, for instance, for the community to have to download a complicated data set in order to see how to color one part of a plot differently from others.  Why do we need to incorporate text for ticks?  Or funny labels?

Here's a basic example:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[Abs[x]/2 > .5, Red, Blue]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) combination:

```
{k, l} = {0, 5};
Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &}, 
  Mesh -> {{k, l}}, 
  MeshStyle -> None,
  MeshShading -> { Automatic, Red}]
```

[image]

This approach avoids blending of colors at boundaries.